# Ползунок у Div, в который добавляю содержимое

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть блок-container, в него добавляются div'ы. Они могут перемещаться и изменять размер. Как добавить scroll в контейнер, чтобы в случае необходимости появлялся ползунок?

`overflow: scroll` или `overflow: auto` не помогают: блок просто выходит за границу контейнера.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dname_id = 1;
  $("#btn2").click(function() {

    var dynDiv = $('<div>')
      .attr('id', 'div_' + dname_id++)
      .css({
        'width': '50px',
        'height': '20px'
      })
      .addClass('resize')
      .html(dname_id - 1);

    $('#container').append(dynDiv);
    //-------------------------------------------------------//
    dynDiv.resizable({
      ghost: true,
        maxHeight: $('#container').height(),
        maxWidth: $('#container').width(),
    });
    dynDiv.draggable({
      containment: 'parent'
    });

    dynDiv.click(function() {

      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var tekdi = $(".selected").attr("id");

      var img1 = "#" + tekdi;
    });
  });
  /*--------------------------------------------*/
  
});
```

```css
.resize {
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#container {
  box-shadow: 4px 0px 18px -1px #0000ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.selected {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  /*box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn2">new div</button>
<br/>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/3/)

*Примечание: пример смотреть на jsfiddle, здесь почему-то не работает (BOPOH)*

Comment: У вашего `#container` поставьте `position: relative`, а то сейчас ваш див не к нему привязан, вот и выходит за его пределы

Comment: @BOPOH, очень выручили,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо было, всего лишь добавить внутренний div, размер которого зависел бы от вложенных элементов.

```
<button id="btn2">new div</button>
<br/>
<div id="container">
    <div id="container_two"></div>
</div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

---

```
#container_two{
    width: 680px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/14/)